# create an SSLContext instance using a Bouncy Castle provider

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, sslengine

I'm stuck at the creation of an SSLContext (which I want to use to instantiate an SSLEngine to handle encrypted transport via the java-nio):

The code

```
String protocol = "TLSv1.2";
Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol,provider.getName());
```

throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SSL for provider BC
at org.bitmash.network.tcp.ssl.SslTransferFactory.<init>(SslTransferFactory.java:43)
at org.bitmash.network.http.HttpsServer.<init>(HttpsServer.java:19)
```

I attached Bouncy Castle's current provider package 'bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar' (which I got from [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)) to the applications classpath as well as to its bootclasspath (via VM-Option -Xbootclasspath/p), but neither solved the problem. I also tried different values for `protocol` (i. e. 'SSL' and 'TLSv1') without any effect.

Also, I found people with similar problems [here](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Support-for-TLS-PSK-td3574184.html) and [here](http://bouncycastle.org/devmailarchive/msg13594.html). But in contrast to them, I'm targeting (and I'm using) Java 7 (or greater), but I still have this problem. Is it -in general- even feasible to use Bouncy Castle this way, or do I have to rewrite my protocol using their respective API instead of oracle's [NIO via SSLEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG) (which is the way I'm doing it right now)?

Thank you so much for any help here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is kind of an old question, but I needed an answer (so I am creating one):

- [Is it possible to] create an SSLContext instance using a Bouncy Castle provider [?]
- No

*Why not?*

Debugging this line of code:

```
Provider [] providers = Security.getProviders();
```

- the default SunJSSE version 1.7 implements the following SSLContext values:

  > Alg.Alias.SSLContext.SSL=TLSv1
  >   Alg.Alias.SSLContext.SSLv3=TLSv1
  >   SSLContext.Default=sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
  >   SSLContext.TLSv1=sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context
  >   SSLContext.TLSv1.1=sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS11Context
  >   SSLContext.TLSv1.2=sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS12Context
- using bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar and adding a new BouncyCastleProvider() to Security, one can observe that there are no SSLContext values available.

This should make sense since Bouncy Castle is a [JCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Cryptography_Extension) implementation, not a [JSSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Secure_Socket_Extension) implementation.

Comment: Now on the other hand, if you were trying to create a key with KeyGenerator, then BC is great for doing that!  KeyGenerator.getInstance("Threefish-256","BC") or KeyGenerator.getInstance("HMACSHA512/224","BC") - you get the point...

Answer (score 10):

Bouncy Castle actually provides a JSSE implementation as of version 1.56.
Just make sure to configure it with a higher priority at the application startup:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
```

or, as alternative, in global `<JRE_HOME>/lib/security/java.security` file:

```
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider
...
security.provider.6=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
```

You can use it then with the standard API:

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

Comment: And note its a separate jar -- bctls-$version not (just) bcprov-$version .

Answer (score 3):

Bouncy Castle implements two types of providers for JSSE:

- An *ordinary* DTLS/TLS and JSSE provider package
- A [FIPS-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) (D)TLS API and JSSE Provider

Current documentation for each provider can be found here: [ordinary](https://bouncycastle.org/docs/tlsdocs1.5on/index.html) and [FIPS-compliant](https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BC-FJA-(D)TLSUserGuide-1.0.9.pdf).

The JAR files for these differ from the JAR file for Bouncy Castle JCE provider. At the time of these writing, the JSSE provider JAR files are called `bctls-jdk15on-1.64.jar` and `bctls-fips-1.0.9.jar`, whereas the JCE provider is `bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar`.

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> ### 2.1 BCJSSE Provider installation into the JRE
>
> Once the bctls jar is installed, the provider class BouncyCastleJsseProvider may need to be installed if it is required in the application globally.
>
> Installation of the provider can be done statically in the JVM by adding it to the provider definition to the `java.security` file in in the `jre/lib/security` directory for your JRE/JDK.
>
> The provider can also be added during execution. If you wish to add the provider to the JVM globally during execution you can add the following imports to your code:
>
> ```
> import java.security.Security
> import org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider
> ```
>
> Then insert the line
>
> ```
> Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
> ```
>
> The provider can then be used by referencing the name `BCJSSE`, for example:
>
> ```
> SSLContext clientContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");
> ```
>
> Alternately if you do not wish to install the provider globally, but use it locally instead, it is possible to pass the provider to the `getInstance()` method on the JSSE class you are creating an instance of.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> SSLContext clientContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS",
>        new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
> ```