# OpenJDK on OpenShift: "NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available"

Tags: openshift, java

I'm running into `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available` with Wildfly 8.2 (OpenJDK 1.8.0_31) on OpenShift (the exception is thrown by `AmazonHttpClient`).

It looks like there is a bug with OpenJDK 1.8 and ECC:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1167153

On of the suggested workarounds requires editing `jre/lib/security/java.security` to disable `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC,ECDHE,ECDH`. 
Or removing `jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar`

Unfortunately I'm not able to do this on OpenShift (missing permissions).

What would be the best workaround here? Can I alternatively switch to Oracle JDK (on OpenShift) which does not have this problem?

**UPDATE**:

I removed Sun java.security.Provider-s and added BouncyCastle instead:

```
static {
  Security.removeProvider("SunEC");
  Security.removeProvider("SUN");
  Security.removeProvider("SunJSSE");
  // ...
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Unfortunately BouncyCastle is *not* a JSSE provider ([create an SSLContext instance using a Bouncy Castle provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906736)) and
`SSLContext.getInstance()` fails with 
`NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLS SSLContext not available`.

I also tried @Rudy De Busscher suggested answer, although I'm not in favor of manual setting
the env variable since it's something that can later easily be forgotten.
Instead, I added the `JAVA_OPTS_EXT` setting to `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.my_custom_env`
and loaded it with `source ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}.my_custom_env` in 
the `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_start` hook.
It didn't worked but since I would still need to use BouncyCastle for JSSE, I have given up this solution.

Fortunatelly I was able to switch back to OpenJDK 1.7 (via `.openshift/markers/java7`)
which "solved" the problem for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.

You can define a properties file to override some of the keys defined in the default JRE file  `jre/lib/security/java.security`

This file can be specified in the JAVA_OPTS_EXT environment property of the OpenShift Gear.

These are the steps that we took to fix the issue.

**Create the file**

- rhc ssc `gearName`
- cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
- vi `override_security.properties`
- content is `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC,ECDHE,ECDH`
- pwd -> and note down (copy) the full path location of the just created file.
- exit

**Set the environment variable**

- rhc env set JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Djava.security.properties=file:`fileLocation` -a `gearName`

**Restart your gear/app**

- rhc app restart -a `gearName`

That did the trick for us.