# Workaround for NoSuchAlgorithmException not working

Tags: centos6, java, tls1.2

I'm getting  the following exception when I enable  SSL debug via *-Djavax.net.debug=ssl*:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available
```

I'm running Centos 6.7, Open JDK 1.8.0_91 & Tomcat 7.0.63

My research indicates that this is a known bug: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9482

I found numerous sources indicating that a workaround for this is to disable the Elliptic Curve cipher algorithms by setting the following property in the *jre/lib/security/java.security* file:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC,ECDHE,ECDH
```

I looked at my *java.security* file and found that these algorithms were already disabled:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keysize < 768, EC, ECDHE, ECDH
```

I tried changing this property to be exactly as shown in the examples I found and that did not work either. I also tried removing the *jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar* file, which again had no effect.

I've carefully traced my installation of Tomcat to ensure that the *jre/lib/security/java.security* file I'm modifying is the one Tomcat is running on.

If anyone has any ideas about what is going on here or how I can work around this problem I would be very grateful to get your input.

This question is related to [OpenJDK on OpenShift: "NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999410) except I'm not using OpenShift and I am able to edit my *java.security* file to attempt the *well known* workaround. My problem is that the workaround does not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenJDK on OpenShift: "NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999410/openjdk-on-openshift-nosuchalgorithmexception-ec-algorithmparameters-not-avai)